# Is it possible to show same address url or Home url for two different projects

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to show same address url or Home url for two different wordpress projects. I mean to say can anyone show different address url for wordpress website. for example visitor come to xyz.com and clicking on some link Is it possible to show abc.com insted of xyz.com.

Comment: you can create links from one website to another, yes, if that's what you're asking. Lots of websites contain links to other sites. I imagine you can create them in wordpress just as easily as a link to a section within wordpress.

Comment: Are you looking to redirect users when they come to your site, or looking to link them to another site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to make redirection in .htaccess file.

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```